# how to remove just the .png from a string

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, png

My problem is that I have to put in and array some image name, but these images name is from with the extension, is there a easy way for remove just the .png from the name my images?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a moment to scan the documentation before posting a question like this. A quick scan of the reference docs for `NSString` would have saved you a lot of time (and you get to learn lots of other methods too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the good way for do that:

```
NSString *nameWithoutExtention = [@"yourImageName.ext" stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```